# I want to serialize an object without using Java's ObjectOutStream directly?

Tags: java, serialization

`public void serialize(IPerson person, OutputStream output) throws Exception {
}`

I want to serialize this object IPerson but I do not want to use Java's built-in ObjectOutputStream, well not directly. This is because IPerson will not use Java's Serializable interface. Any ideas?

Comment: You can either write and read the important information manually or implement serializable. If you do it manually you have to keep the write and read functions up to date if you add fields to the class.
How complex is the class? Is it yours to edit?

Comment: AFAIK, Externalizable interface is made for this purpose.

Comment: Depending on your needs, [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) may be sufficient.

Comment: @Xvolks I think the Externalizable  interface would work, could you direct me to a resource of how to use it? I never used that interface before.

Comment: @VGR XMLEncoder having just briefly reading about it, seems promising. Perhaps you can direct me to a resource of how to use?

Comment: XMLEncoder's documentation has an example.  Most of the time, it's really that easy, at least with JavaBeans-compliant classes (that is, classes with properties defined by matching get-methods and set-methods).  You might want to make use of XMLEncoder's inherited setExceptionListener method to be sure your write succeeded.  There's also Oracle's [Using XMLEncoder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/persistence4-140124.html) article, but that's far more detailed and technical than what most people will ever need.

Comment: @VGR I am trying to user XMLEncoder but it requires me to use a class with a no-arg constructor, which I cannot make possible, any work arounds?

Comment: @Xvolks I looked into Externalizable and it requires Serializable to be implemented which is what I do not want to do.

Comment: You'll have to create your own serialization mechanism. But this is bad practice IMHO.

Comment: Yes, there is a workaround.  You can call [setPersistenceDelegate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Encoder.html#setPersistenceDelegate-java.lang.Class-java.beans.PersistenceDelegate-).  But that will make things considerably more complicated.  (I still have some trouble understanding it, myself.)  It's worth looking into, but you may decide it's not worth the effort.